# Multiselect dropdown control - Primeng - Angular 6 - Select all options by default on page load and display them as selected label

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angular

I have a priming multi-select drop-down control. On page load, all options should be selected and the selected label should display "All selected". How to fetch the "Select All" checkbox status in priming multi-select control?

When all options are selected, the dropdown displays 3 items selected.

Here instead of 3 items selected, it should display "All". And all the options should be selected by default on page load. Help in resolving this.

```
AppComponent.html

        <div id="statusdrpdown" #statusdropdown>
          <p-multiSelect [options]="status" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" [maxSelectedLabels]="1" class="multiselectcss" [filter]="false" (onPanelShow) =" funShow()"  optionLabel="name"></p-multiSelect>
          <label id="statuslbl" class="drpdownlbl"><br />Status</label>
        </div>


    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    App.Component.ts

        import { Component , ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
        import { SampleData } from './sample-data';
        @Component({
         selector: 'my-app',
         templateUrl: './app.component.html',
         styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
        })
        export class AppComponent  {
          @ViewChild("statusdropdown", { read: ElementRef }) tref: ElementRef;
           status: SampleData[];

          selectedStatus: SampleData[];
          constructor() { }

          ngOnInit() {
            this.status = [
          { name: 'Active', value: '1' },
              { name: 'Inactive', value: '2' },
              { name: 'Status-complete-or-active', value: '3' },
        ];
      }
      funShow() {
        var h = this.tref.nativeElement;
        var text = document.createTextNode("All");
        h.childNodes[0].lastChild.lastChild.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].after(text);
      }
    }

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    App.module.ts
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
    import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';
     import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MultiSelectModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

---

```
Primeng version - in package.json
```

"primeicons": "^1.0.0",
        "primeng": "^7.0.0-beta.1"

---

```
SampleData interface - 

export interface SampleData {
    name: string,
    value: string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this when your data is present (`Constructor`, `OnInit` ..) :

```
   this.status.map((item) => this.selectedStatus.push(item));
```

**PS:** And do not forget to initialize your `selectedStatus` to empty array so that you can fill it later.

[**Here is a stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-primeng-ygb2xv?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts) for your case.

Comment: Exactly!! I have pushed the array into selectedStatus. If you see the dropdown, it displays 3 selected. I have to display "All Selected" instead of the number. How to achieve this?

Comment: @J.Doe I think there is no such option in the multiselect component, unless you override the whole component by downloading it and edit its behavior to what's needed then change your import to refer on your customized component instead of the primeng's one.

Comment: Thanks selem mn. I will customize it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set: `maxSelectedLabels` property to "2" and the `selectedItemsLabel` to "All selected" in your template markup.